# Suggestion Required between JLabel and JButton for MouseListener

Tags: java, jbutton, jlabel, mouselistener, imageicon

Well, my program is nearly finished. I am using `JLabel`s with `ImageIcon`. But some time when I clicked outside of a `JLabel`/`ImageIcon` the mouse event is generated un-wantedly on some other label.

I heard that `ImageIcon` in `JLabel`s are not good for `MouseListener`, because even in my program sometime events are wrongly generate when I clicked on one `JLabel` `ImageIcon` which disabled for mouselistener then an active mouselistener jlabel catch that event and activated.

Please suggest me should I drop the idea for using `JLabel` with `ImageIcon` and use `JButtonp` instead?

Your Suggestions and comments will guide me

Thanks

Comment: Are the components overlapping?

Comment: *"should i drop the idea for using JLabel with ImageIcon. and use JButtons Instead."*  Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Conceptually, a label is not intended to be interactive (except tooltips or mouseover effects).
2. Next you should think of your users. What about those who prefer to use keyboard?
3. Buttons have a standard (well implemented) behaviour for different mouse events? (Try to click on it and drag the mouse out, for instance)

Go with `JButton` and `ActionListener`.